# SPLIT_STR not working with the foreign languages

Tags: mysql

I got the function `SPLIT_STR` from [blog.fedecarg.com](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)

Here is that code

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

If I try to select like

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR('accountName;โอมTEST;No.454646;i;2013-8-23', ';' , 2) as 'RES';
```

The result is

```
_________________
|      RES      |
| ------------- |
|    โอมTEST    |
_________________
```

If I change that index to 3

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR('accountName;โอมTEST;No.454646;i;2013-8-23', ';' , 3) as 'RES';
```

The expected value is `No.454646`

But the result is

```
_________________
|      RES      |
| ------------- |
|      4646     |
_________________
```

Is function `SPLIT_STR` has bug?

NOTE : If you cut the foreign languages(`โอม`) out. The problem will solved.

How can I use this function by working well with  the foreign languages, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) returns the string length in bytes; your foreign language characters are probably 2 or 3 bytes UTF sequences. 
Try to replace `LENGTH` with [`CHAR_LENGHT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length), which returns the length of the string measured in characters, in the function definition.

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bb2d/1