# FUNCTION split_str does not exist

Tags: mysql

while I am running MySQL query, I am getting this error

```
 Error in a query (1305): FUNCTION dbname.split_str does not exist
```

I am calling this

```
 SELECT split_str("ABC,,BA,,abc",",,",3);
```

I don't know why I am getting this error, I tried all servers i have

Comment: MySQL does not have a `split_str` function.  If you can include more samples of data which you are trying to split, maybe someone can give you a workaround.

Comment: it is not a mysql inbuilt function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPLIT\_STR not working with the foreign languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099703/split-str-not-working-with-the-foreign-languages)

Comment: MySQL does not have a split_str function  however mssql/sqlserver does have this function.

Comment: @Jbadminton these questions are different, I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @Tim,

I got my solution, I understand split_str is not an inbuilt function and I have to add this function in my DB.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, "");
```

I found this function from where I saw the split_str function and after excecuting, these lines was solved my issues.